# Use Objectify with Vert.x

Tags: java, objectify, google-cloud-datastore, vert.x

Is it possible to integrate Objectify in a Vert.x application ?

Let me give you some context. I have a REST API exposed by Vert.x (3.3.0) that interacts with Google Cloud Datastore using gcloud-java library. Everything works fine but I want to use a higher level API to make all that code easier to read and more maintainable.

[Objectify setup](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Setup) indicates that

> Objectify requires a filter to clean up any thread-local transaction contexts and pending asynchronous operations that remain at the end of a request.

The thing is, I have no web.xml and Objectify seems to need a servlet filter to work.

Answer (score 2):

It is my understanding that Objectify is specifically designed for Google App Engine. It works well within applications that are deployed to GAE. I did not have any luck using it outside of GAE (not even in Compute Engine). Since you mentioned that you are using the gcloud-java library to access the Cloud Datastore, you might want to check out [Catatumbo](https://github.com/sai-pullabhotla/catatumbo), an Object Mapping and Persistence Framework that is built on top of gcloud-java. Catatumbo is similar to JPA. Catatumbo is an open source project distributed under the Apache v2 license.

Comment: What do you plan for this project ? Does it has a caching feature ? Does it support or will support Ref and Key like objectify does ?

Comment: Support for Keys, Parent Keys and Key References already exists in the current released version. There is no support for Caching yet, but can be implemented. Please feel free to create issues in GitHub for any features that are missing. Be sure to provide as much information as possible.